# dynamically create a new activity by pressing of different buttons in different activities

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-activity

my problem goes like this-

this is a commercial application in which users can purchase different products they see within app..
there is one `view cart` button available on the main screen
there are 10 different products available in an activity and there are 3 such activities( each of them containing various different products)
these products are arranged in a linear fashion (linear layout).
every product is having an `add to cart` image button.

what i want is, when the user presses that button, 3 things should happen..

1. a new activity will be created containing that product information (when the user presses another "add to cart" button, this new product will come below the previous product and so on).
2. there is one cart button in the menu bar, that cart should show a number equal to the nos of product in the cart.
3. its simple, a small flash notification that the product has been added to the cart.

any help will be deeply appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You would see some benefit by using `Fragment`s instead. Use a main `Activity` as a "switchboard" and multiple `Fragment` instances to show the per item details.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to dynamically create a new Activity. Taking into consideration that you call yourself a newbie in android development, I can only tell you what to study to accomplish your plan. 
First, learn to make an Activity that will contain a ListView. Make an XML layout for your ListView items, containing TextViews, Buttons, whatever you want. Then, make an adapter that will fill items with corresponding values (texts, button names, images, etc). 
And second, make them all clickable (onItemClickListener or an onClickListener for every button) and make your Activity get inflated with a Fragment containing TextViews, ImageViews, etc... whatever you need to represent information about the item selected.
The best practical way is to make an empty Activity with an empty Fragment. The last one will be either inflated (populated) or even replaced with whatever things you need. 
Sorry, but teaching you how to make all these things technically is beyond the scope of any sensible answer that someone can post here. It's all the matter of study and practice. But I hope the vector of study I gave you is transparent and affordable.

Comment: i have done all these things, the app is complete, just facing this problem